# Can I travel with Ryanair with a DSLR special bag as second hand luggage?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, gear, photography, ryanair

As of 1st December 2014, Ryanair allows to carry a second hand-luggage which not exceeds the exact measures given [in their TOS](https://www.ryanair.com/en/terms-and-conditions/article8/).

I'm travelling with them next month and I plan to carry a second bag (smaller than the second hand-luggage dimensions) with my DSLR camera and some accessories.

Although at first impression it seems clear that I can carry it without having to pay extra, there is some controversy in Internet about which kind of "bag" can be taken as the secondary one. I have read that they only admit a "duty-free" or a woman bag as secondary hand luggage.

Is there such "type of bag" limit or some limitations on which objects can be carried in this second hand-luggage?

Comment: Have you called them about this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page is clear and direct: https://www.ryanair.com/en/terms-and-conditions/regulations-cabinbaggage/ - you are allowed:

> One cabin bag weighing up to 10 kg with maximum dimensions of 55cm x 40cm x 20cm, plus 1 small bag up to 35 x 20 x 20 cms may be carried per passenger.

So if your camera bag is within those dimensions and the total of both bags is not much more than 10 kg (just to be conservative and anticipate the possible objection if your camera bag is heavy), you should be fine.